# subscribe to websocket subject create multiple connections

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

Sharing a websocket connection among multiple components duplicates the connection.

```
export class NotificationService {
  notification;
  destroy$ = new Subject();
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}
  createWs() {
      this.notification = this.appService
        .getTicket()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(data =>
            webSocket(`wss://echo.websocket.org/`).pipe(
              takeUntil(this.destroy$)
            )
          )
        )
        .pipe(
          catchError(e => {
            return throwError(e);
          }),
          retryWhen(errors =>
            errors.pipe(
              concatMap((_, iteration) => timer(Math.pow(2, iteration) * 1000)),
              take(10)
            )
          )
        );
  }

  filterNotification() {
    if (!this.notification) {
      this.createWs();
    }
    return this.notification;
  }
}
```

Calling `this.notificationService.filterNotification()` in various components create multiples websocket connections. Per documentation [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket),

> When WebSocketSubject is subscribed, it attempts to make a socket connection, unless there is one made already. This means that many subscribers will always listen on the same socket, thus saving resources. If however, two instances are made of WebSocketSubject, even if these two were provided with the same url, they will attempt to make separate connections

A new instance is not created, but the subscription duplicates the connection.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-ws?file=src/app/notification.service.ts)

Comment: try using `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`, honestly I don't understand the need to subscribe to `webSocket` repeatedly each time the observable returned by `getTicket()` emits

Comment: Actually I need getTicket - an http request - to add a token to the websocket url

Comment: Each time `createWs()` is called `this.notification` is assigned a new observable but the previous value is kept subscribed

Comment: `createWs` is called only once

Answer (score 1):

The `mergeMap` was triggering a new websocket instance for each subscription leading to the duplication. By keeping a reference to the inner observable, the later is returned instead of opening a new websocket

```
this.notification = this.appService
        .getTicket()
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(data =>
            this.ws ? this.ws : this.ws = webSocket(`wss://echo.websocket.org/`).pipe(
              takeUntil(this.destroy$)
            )
          )
        )
```